# Does all drawing in Android happen in a single thread?

Tags: android, drawable, android-5.0-lollipop

I have custom checkbox PNGs.  I didn't create disabled images; instead, the custom drawable, when drawing a disabled checkbox, sets a "graying-out" color filter to the state-list drawable and then draws it.  That worked quite well until version 4.4.4.  Unfortunately, in Android L, once a disabled checkbox is drawn, this color filter is applied to all checkboxes as soon as they are redrawn.

I am wondering whether drawing in Android L happens in multiple threads.  That's the only explanation I can find for this "propagation" of the color filter to the other checkboxes...

Comment: You need to mutate drawables before calling setter methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is an optimization, as Android is caching the image drawn and then just re-using the cached image. You said you already have a state list drawable so you should just add a state image for the state enabled="false".

Comment: This thought has crossed my mind.  Two things: 1) I do have **separate drawables** for enabled and disabled states, although they draw the same image (through `Canvas.drawBitmap`) -- so it beats me how Android figures out what image to cache; 2) Any way to turn off that optimization?

Answer (score 0):

In Android L there are two threads that handle UI: the main (UI Tool Kit) thread and Render thread. The Render thread is new to L and is specific to Animations. [Threads in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)

Comment: Does the Render thread call `Drawable.draw()` or `View.onDraw()` methods?  I was writing the app under the assumption that all of these are called from a single thread (hence `Paint`s etc. are reused).

Comment: The how of the Render thread is not widely known. I would imagine it would have to draw because its sole purpose is to give animations a thread to run on, as to not hold up the tool kit thread from loading and managing views.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  May be helpful to others.  This is is probably a bug in Android L.

The `Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect, RectF, Paint)` function, if the `Paint` argument contains a color filter, caches the copied part of the image **with the color filter applied**.  Next time the same part of the `Bitmap` is drawn, even if the `Paint` contains a `null` color filter, the image from the cache is used.  In order to avoid this effect, you need to `drawBitmap` with a different, non-null color filter in `Paint`.  I created a color filter from an identity matrix as follows.

```
private static final float[] arrEmptyFilter =
{
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
};

ColorMatrixColorFilter emptyFilter = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ?
    new ColorMatrixColorFilter(arrEmptyFilter) : null;
```

Then everywhere, instead of setting a paint's color filter to null, I set it to `emptyFilter`.  Problem solved.

I don't know if the other versions of `drawBitmap()`

Comment: Well, it worked.  And mutating everything was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It looks like there is a bug. Would you mind filing an issue on the [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) with some code we can use to reproduce this?

Comment: I can't reproduce it with simple means.  I'll try to take another look over the next weekend.

Comment: @alanv: It can be reproduced if the "target SDK" is set to 10.  I also used a few custom drawables wrapped in one another -- but the effect is quite clear: if a null color filter is replaced by a non-null no-effect filter, the result changes.  Do you want it?  It consists of several files.

Comment: You should post or link them in the question. "a few custom drawables" could easily introduce a bug unrelated to the framework.